# .ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android

when I share my app to other one then my app crash but when I run my app direct fron studio then app run properly but I have seen all solution but nothing works for me.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.amit.workoutdocent-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.amit.workoutdocent-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6948)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6480)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:230)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1888)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.amit.workoutdocent-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.amit.workoutdocent-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                     at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6933)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6480) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:230) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1888) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Answer (score 2):

if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you have to use the multidex support library as:

module-level.gradle ---

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15 
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and in your Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base);
 MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Awesome! my `MultiDex.install(this);` was in `onCreate()`, move to `attachBaseContext()` and app works like charm

Answer (score 1):

Lowered my gradle version from 2.3.3 to 2.3.0 in build.gradle file, clean and build the project. Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it by Disabling **Instant Run** in Android Studio

**Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure google play services and Firebase dependecies are the same version in your build.gradle. Then, use invalidate cache and restart option in Android Studio